# Базы данных для быстрой операции записи

Tags: база-данных

Подскажите базы данных которые позволяют проводить быстрые операции записи, вставки, удаления, обновления. Те базы данных которые я тестировал в том числе Mysql и Postgresql не давали желаемой скорости записи, я использовал индексирование и это  увеличивало скорость записи, но все же желаемой скорости я так и не достиг. Может есть базы данных которые быстро производят операции записи?

Comment: Вы что-то очень странное пишете. Можете привести пример запроса, которым вы производите вставку?

Comment: Александр, обыкновенная операция insert или update

Comment: Какой объём данных вы вставляете за раз и сколько времени эта операция у вас занимает?

Comment: Александр, за раз приблизительно 6 мегабайт, postgresql справляется за 8 секунд с учетом того что я осуществляю  вставку данных  из java кода используя jdbc драйвер.

Comment: Боюсь, в вашем случае всё упирается в ограничение скорости работы жёсткого диска. Посоветовать могу только сменить HDD диск на SSD.